# Is tally db accessible via odbc in android?

Tags: android, odbc

Is it possible to access tally database by using odbc connectivity in android ?
I searched a lot I got http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01038.html this link here they integrate excel database is it possible to integrate tally database using odbc connection in android?

If any one having idea revert please

Comment: do you need this database(i mean location of file) on the device(1) or on remote machine/location(2)? Now  if you need 1 then use SQLite(Android has built-in support) and if need 2 use REST service

Comment: I have to use odbc connection only is it possible?